# Can I add UI Elements in Settings Flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

In my metro app, I can attach some settings tab like the following image.

[image: Settings with custom tab add]

But I don't know how can I add an UI Element like on-off button in this screen(I want it directly in the settings screen, not inside any customised tab).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is it recomended then to create a settings tab if I have to add only one UI element in that?

Comment: I haven't checked but maybe if it just accepts a string you could use a ding font and insert some icon style glyph or maybe use some extended ascii like #254 to get something in there that might resemble something you could use for it.